# Create a dataframe with the results of a simple linear regression

Tags: r

I have a time serie of individual body condition index. I want to determine, for each individual, the evolution of the body condition index over time. In other words, I want to create a linear regression for each individual and then gather all the results (intercept and slope) into a dataframe that would look like this:

First column : Individual id

Second column : Intercept

Thirs column: Slope

This is what I tried (with only a sample of my dataset), but I only get a list of all the results and I don't know how to reunite them into a single dataframe:

```
individual <- c(1,1,6,8,8,9,9,9,12,12)
day <- c(4,17,12,12,17,3,9,22,13,20)
condition <- c(0.72, 0.72, 0.67, 0.73, 0.76, 0.65, 0.68, 0.78, 0.73, 0.71)       
test <- data.frame(individual, day, condition)
ind.id <- unique(test$individual)
ind.list <- lapply(1:length(ind.id), function(i){ subset(test, test$individual==ind.id[i])})
lms <- lapply(ind.list, lm, formula=condition~day)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the package `plyr` which has some nice benefits for you:

1. function `ddply()` will estimate the lm() by individual, or whatever other grouping variable you specify
2. Returns a data.frame by default

Code:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(test, "individual", function(x) {
  model <- lm(condition ~ day, data = x)
  coef(model)
})
```

Returns:

```
  individual (Intercept)           day
1          1   0.7200000  1.207763e-17
2          6   0.6700000            NA
3          8   0.6580000  6.000000e-03
4          9   0.6242403  6.978799e-03
5         12   0.7671429 -2.857143e-03
```

If you don't want to use plyr, or just want to know how to do this with base R, here's one approach. Note that by default, your list object `lms` does not have any names associated with it, so you'll want to make sure that `ind.id` matches to the right coefficients. I'd probably use the plyr approach myself.

```
> cbind(ind.id, do.call("rbind",lapply(lms, coef)))
   ind.id (Intercept)           day
1       1   0.7200000  1.207763e-17
6       6   0.6700000            NA
8       8   0.6580000  6.000000e-03
9       9   0.6242403  6.978799e-03
12     12   0.7671429 -2.857143e-03
```

Comment: (+1) no fair using `plyr` for the whole problem!

Comment: @Justin - work smarter not harder :) Hadley has a pretty similar example in his paper on plyr where he uses plyr to make 100s of diagnostic plots from lm() models.

Comment: Here is the link for that paper: _The Split-Apply-Combine Strategy for Data Analysis_ [http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper)

Comment: Working smarter, I like that! Thanks!

Comment: Using plyr is a lazy approach and simply a way to escape the reality. Learn the hardest way.

Answer (score 2):

I like `plyr` for these cases:

```
ldply(lms, function(x) x$coefficients)


  (Intercept)           day
1   0.7200000  1.207763e-17
2   0.6700000            NA
3   0.6580000  6.000000e-03
4   0.6242403  6.978799e-03
5   0.7671429 -2.857143e-03
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at `lmList` in the `nlme` package.  More generally you may want to fit a single mixed model (`nlme` or `lme4`) rather than individual models for each subject.

Comment: Thanks, I already use lme to analyse my data, the individual lm are for another purpose.